# XPages repeat from array value field

Tags: hyperlink, xpages, repeat

I have a field which value is an array of strings.

Example: Mom, dad, son, etc.

It is possible to repeat a link with those values?

Example:

[Mom](http://mom.com)

[dad](http://dad.com)

[son](http://son.com)

And when I click on the link to have a href=www."fieldvalue".com.

**EDIT:** it is not vector, it is Array.

Comment: I don't get what you're looking for.  Could you be a little more detailed or maybe post a mockup?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your repeat control.  For the value add in your field name.  Something like :
document1.getItemValue("myMultiValueField")

I THINK that should repeat your field assuming it is a real multi-value.  The comma deliminated string would require more work.  So I'm not talking about that...

Make sure the collection name / var name of the repeat is something like "rowData"

rowData should then be a String.

Drop a link control inside the repeat.

Compute the label to be simple "rowData".  (no quotes in the code)

Compute the URL - which I THINK is "value" in all properties of the link

That's just javaScript so you should be able to do something like:

```
return "http://" + rowData + ".com"
```

That's rough - you'll have to play with it but if I follow you correctly should work.

For a comma deliminated String...  in the repeat control you'd need to use SSJS or @functions to break that into an array so the repeat can work on it.

Comment: How exactly the repeat control work? What exactly does repeat? A document or a vector?

Comment: A Repeat control can repeat ANY collection really.  A document collection, a view entry collection, an Array of Strings, a Java List...  a multi-value field..
You then assign a variable to get to the original row.  The variable is called "Collection Name" in the pretty panel which is pretty dumb name really.  But if you go into all properties its called "var".
This var becomes whatever object is being repeated.  So a string if it's an array of strings.  Typically its an XSPViewEntry I think if the repeat is just bound to a view.

Comment: Note there have been MANY shows on Repeat Controls on my Screencast:  NotesIn9.  I have an episode guide here:  http://www.mindmeister.com/280533435/notesin9  Maybe you want to start with "Intro to Repeat Controls". It's an OLD show but for the most part should still be relevant information.

Comment: I've done the way you said but it seems that it doesn't want to repeat. I though first that is a string and used: `document1.getItemValue("myMultiValueField").split(",")` but I've got an error that says I've a vector. Then why it doesn't repeat?

Comment: The repeat is a vector but the link is a string. It suppose to be like that? It doesn't want to repeat the link

Comment: My bad... It seems that it is an array returned to the field from which I get the values for the repeat. Then why the repeat value is a vector class? Very strange...

Comment: Not sure I'm following.  When you get a multi-value field it should come back as a Vector I believe because that's what the very OLD Notes Java API does.  They don't have List<String> stuff...
One thing I'll often do when I have problems with repeat controls is just add a computed control bound to rowData or whatever the varName is.  Often that can help me figure out what I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

In your repeat you'll need to map the value attribute to the Vector and set a var property, which is how you will reference each element. Note: a comma-separated string is a single value, and a repeat requires multiple values. So you'll need to convert it to a Vector or some other multi-value object.

Within the repeat you can use any other control and compute the value as you would elsewhere. To access each element in your repeat control's source (i.e. each String in your Vector, in this case), use the variable name you've defined in the var property.